# Why does this IAM policy have a syntax error?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm new to/learning about AWS, currently using `LocalStack` in lieu of real live `AWS`.

`arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/path/to/foo.json` is a valid `S3` key to an object in a newly-created `S3` bucket. Because the bucket is newly created and pristine, other than the one file upload, nothing in it is externally accessible. I'm trying to learn about `IAM` by working through examples to create a policy that grants read-access to parts of a `S3` bucket.

I created the following policy file based on [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-policy.html) from the `AWS` CLI reference:

```
$ cat ./policy
{
  "Version": "2020-04-27",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/path/to/foo.json"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From the same linked example, I tried to create my policy with this command, which failed:

```
$ aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4593 iam create-policy --policy-name my-bucket-policy --policy-document file://policy

An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.
```

**Why did this command fail, or is there a way I can get a more-descriptive error message?**

(`policy` is a file in the `cwd` where I execute the `aws` CLI command)

By my reading, the error message implies malformed JSON, but linters like https://jsonlint.com/ indicate that the text is valid JSON. Moreover, the changes from the source example are minimal and would appear reasonable: `"Version"` is changed to today's date, and the `"Resource"` `ARN` is changed to what's relevant to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is incorrect version given. It should be: "2012-10-17"

Edit: Mistake with Principle. See comments. Principle is [required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_resource-based) for resource-based policies:

> Principal (Required in only some circumstances) – If you create a **resource-based policy**, you **must indicate** the account, user, role, or federated user to which you would like to allow or deny access. If you are creating an **IAM permissions policy** to attach to a user or role, you **cannot include** this element. The principal is implied as that user or role.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. :| Thank you. :) I looked at the `"Version"` in the example, and jumped to assuming it was meant to be *today's date*; I didn't make the connection that the date is "enumerated" to represent the version language syntax.

Comment: fyi, I actually get the same error if I include `"Principal": "*"` - but it works without it. I may follow up with a separate question.

Comment: @StoneThrow I eddited the answer. The examples of `Principal` field use are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) to double check its syntax.